# Iterate the row in dataframe based on the column values in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For 'N' farmers on the invoice each owner will be split 'N' times. I want the row to split as per expected output in spark scala.

source Data:

```
INVNUM  PRODNUM CUSTNAME    LANDOWNERS
1       1       Sonu        farmer
1       1       Ramu        farmer
1       1       Alec        owner
1       1       Prashanth   owner
```

Expected output:

```
INVNUM  PRODNUM CUSTNAME    Shareownername
1       1       Sonu        Sonu --> same name here as Sonu is Farmer
1       1       Ramu        Ramu --> same name here as Ramu is Farmer
1       1       Alec        Sonu --> split two times for Sonu and Ramu as sharewoner for Alec
1       1       Alec        Ramu
1       1       Prashanth   Sonu --> split twice Sonu and Ramu as sharewoner for Prashanth
1       1       Prashanth   Ramu
```

Answer (score 1):

Owners can be joined with farmers for get split, and united by "union" with farmers:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, "Sonu", "farmer"),
  (1, 1, "Ramu", "farmer"),
  (1, 1, "Alec", "owner"),
  (1, 1, "Prashanth", "owner")
).toDF("INVNUM", "PRODNUM", "CUSTNAME", "LANDOWNERS")

val farmers = df.where($"LANDOWNERS" === "farmer")
val owners = df.where($"LANDOWNERS" === "owner")

val split = owners.alias("o")
  .join(farmers.alias("f"), Seq("INVNUM", "PRODNUM"))
  .select($"o.INVNUM", $"o.PRODNUM", $"o.CUSTNAME", $"f.CUSTNAME".alias("Shareownername"))


val result = farmers
  .select($"INVNUM", $"PRODNUM", $"CUSTNAME", $"CUSTNAME".alias("Shareownername"))
  .unionAll(split)
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+---------+--------------+
|INVNUM|PRODNUM|CUSTNAME |Shareownername|
+------+-------+---------+--------------+
|1     |1      |Sonu     |Sonu          |
|1     |1      |Ramu     |Ramu          |
|1     |1      |Alec     |Ramu          |
|1     |1      |Alec     |Sonu          |
|1     |1      |Prashanth|Ramu          |
|1     |1      |Prashanth|Sonu          |
+------+-------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Pasha for your suggestion, I would try this :)

Comment: Hi Pasha, the inner join would fail to retrieve the owner records, if the rows in the source have only owner and no farmer in the same invnum. So we may have to go with the Full outer join I guess.

Comment: Left  join can be used:       .join(farmers.alias("f"), Seq("INVNUM", "PRODNUM"),"left")

Comment: I tried with left join (farmers leftjoin owners) and then left join(owners leftjoin farmers)  and then union to get all the records without any skip but we have to do so many joins, do we have any other suggestion